# How do I review my own code?

Tags: code-reviews, solo-development

I'm working on a project solo and have to maintain my own code. Usually code review is done not by the code author, so the reviewer can look at the code with the fresh eyes — however, I don't have such luxury. What practices can I employ to more effectively review my own code?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, at least not effectively - you can crowd source a review team at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if your code is not proprietary though

Comment: You cannot review your own code.  If you cannot get other humans, I would consider the best you can do to use as many static analyzers you can get your hands on, and enable ALL warnings.

Comment: Reviewing your own code is easy. Write a piece code. Step away for 2 weeks/months/years as you continue to learn and develop other software. Come back to that piece and try to understand what the code is doing. You know you learned something when you think: "what kind of idiot wrote this?!".

Comment: @YuriyZubarev But what if you don't want to wait for weeks/month/years?

Comment: You can review your code in an altered mind state. Or you can code in an altered mind state and delegate a code review to your normal boring self.

Comment: @anatoliiG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forget-Me-Now

Comment: try writing some unit tests for your code. that should give you some feedback.

Comment: In my first ever comp sci lecture, decades ago, the lecturer recommended we each get a cat. When there is a bug, you sit with the cat and go through the listing, line by line, explaining to the cat "the bug can't possibly be in this line. The bug ... D'oh!".  I swear that it doesn't work without the cat. Perhaps the same method could be extended to code review?

Comment: @Mawg what you are doing sounds like rubber duck debugging. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging with a cat. I might have to try that with my cat, but I'd feel silly. More so than when I talk to an actual rubber duck

Answer (score 98, accepted):

First of all, make use of tools to check as much as you can. Tests (backed up with some reasonable code coverage) will give you some confidence of the correctness of the code. Static analysis tools can catch a lot of best practice things. There will always be issues that you need human eyes on to determine though and you will never do as good a job reviewing your own stuff as someone else, there are some things you can do to help however

- check tests exist and pass (possibly have a target test coverage, though you may need to break this in certain cases, but you should be able to justify why)
- check Static analysis passes (there will also be false negatives here but that is fine as long as you can justify why then its fine to suppress them)
- maintain a check list of further things to check in review (ideally add this as new static analysis rules if possible) make sure you check anything the SA can't check, e.g., are comments still valid, are things named appropriately (naming things is of course, one of the 2 hard problems known to computer science)
- if a fault is identified check if the cause is systemic and look at why it wasn't found in earlier tests or reviews

This of course is useful when you are reviewing others code as well

Comment: Concerning the check-list, having a [spec](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/AardvarkSpec.html) is super useful.

Comment: I don't like checklists. They make reviewer concentrate on checklist instead of thinking the problem, the solution, and many other things.  So I suggest make them minimal.

Answer (score 58):

Take a look into the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site. It is for sharing code from projects you are working on for [peer review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **Code Review Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code. We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.
>
> If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases

You can also use code static analysis tools to detect certain kind of problems, but they are going to produce false alarms in some cases, and can not suggest how to improve the design.

Comment: That's an excellent answer to the question "How to get my code reviewed", and a good advice in general (I will definitely do that) — but still a little offtopic.

Comment: @golergka Off topic in what way? The question is : "How do I review my own code?" with nobody around.

Comment: I normally don't like a 5 word answer, but this one is *just so right*.

Comment: @VJovic maybe off topic because a direct answer to "how do I review my own code without people" is not "use these people". I think OP is looking for tips on assessing own code if there are no others available whatsoever. (ex. what if codereview is down, or coder has no Internet access when needing to review code, etc)

Comment: At best this is only a limited solution.  Continually putting your entire daily output on CR.SE isn't feasible since large chinks of it's going to be fairly mundane boilerplate code.  CR.SE is also not going to be much help with spotting problems that require a non-trivial understanding of the entire application architecture or domain the app is written for.  From informal, look at coworkers code when it's checked in style, reviews where I work these sort of errors are probably more common than the ones that would be suitable for catching via CR.SE.

Comment: @VJovic kind of offtopic because it clearly isn't feasible to do *real* code review on a stack website, just some non-working/odd bits and bops. You can't paste your whole source code in there.

Comment: **The real value in reviewing** is getting pieces of code you never though would ever present any problem spotted and highlighted as *non-obvious* nor *self explaining* or even *non logically correct*. You can't post the snippet to `code review` if you are not already aware it's a problematic one.

Comment: @ZJR Well, is the code in your projects 100% reviewed? If yes, your engineers have too much free time. As for your 2nd comment, I don't see problems in asking for a code review in a code that you think is perfect.

Comment: @YannisRizos Does the current answer fit the guidelines?

Comment: @VJovic no, it does not, but I know it would benefit from it: it's chock full of WTFs I can't even see anymore. Ah, just because you made me thought about it, a note on the side: random reviewers, in certain circumstances, can prove a waste of time: sometimes you need someone that is at ease with the domain and/or the techniques (in my case, I'm thinking regexps) involved, or they'll just **wtf** everything.

Comment: @ZJR Any code review can fail. Has it ever happened to you that you do a code review with a possible solution, and then few days later you get a big idea that makes the code review's solution looks like a wtf?

Comment: @VJovic it depends on what depth of review you're asking about and the size of the team.  None of the projects I've worked on did any sort of formal code; so I normally do quick sanity check lookovers on all code added to source control.  At ~5 minutes/developer/day this won't scale to large teams, but does generally flag major problems other devs missed early on.

Comment: There are IPR issues. Posting the code on StackExchange means releasing it under Creative Commons. The OP may not be allowed to do that, especially if its a closed-source project.

Comment: @ZJR I whole heartedly disagree with your arguments against this answer. Plenty of people get quality reviews from strangers on CR everyday. Now, the arguments about licensing hold true, but CR is a completely viable option for a solo dev working on an open source project.

Comment: Say, @ZJR, where's your CR.SE account? ;)

Answer (score 31):

I've developed several totally different persons in my head.
One of them is not even a programmer!
We're chatting, discussing latest news and reviewing each other's code.

I strongly recommend my approach.

ps
He is not kidding.

Comment: My names are Bill, Jeff, Bob, and Alice, and we approve this message.

Answer (score 23):

I agree whit jk-s opinion that single-person review is not as efficient as 2 person review. however you can try to make the best of it:

**short term review (shortly after the code was produced)**

I am using git as a local repository. Whenever I have finished a feature or fixed a bug I transfer the changes to the repository.

Before i check in I compare what I have changed in my code and rethink:

- do variable/method/classnames still reflect what they are used for?

**long term review (6 months after the code was produced)**

I ask myself:

- can I describe in one sentense what a class/method/variable does?
- how easy is it to use a class in isolation (whitout the other classes) or write a unittest for?

Comment: +1 for short term review suggestion. Using git to view all changes between different points in time can really help cleaning up the code.

Comment: I quiet like the long term review idea, I think I'd probably combine it into a general project wash-up review though and maybe not review all code (then again I don't tend to do solo development much)

Comment: I try to do something in between: review my code in about a month. I also like the 6 month review.

Answer (score 19):

First, set your code aside for as long as practical. Work on something else, some other piece of code. Even after a day, you will be amazed at what you will find.

Second, document your code. Many programmers hate to document their code, but make yourself sit down and write out documentation, how to use the code and how it works. By looking at your code in a different way, you will find mistakes.

It has been said that true mastery of a subject is the ability to teach it to someone else. With documentation you are trying to teach someone else your code.

Answer (score 16):

Transform this debugging technique to a code review technique: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

The concept works wonders for putting you into a proper mindset for working through code as if it were new.

Comment: I believe the duck technique has been independently invented at multiple sites; here's a great story about it: http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html

Comment: These days, my rubber duck is the Stack Exchange ask-a-question form. The desire to write a *good question* does the trick.

Comment: Excellent advice. It's even better as I already have a rubber duck on my desk (it's been here as a model for one of my game characters, but I guess it won't mind additional job of an IT consultant).

Comment: @KevinReid, I would *love* to see some stats on abandoned SE posts - especially ones that people have been typing for longer than 60s on. I know I've done that same thing myself at least 5 times.

Comment: Wah! I didn't know this was " a thing". I just commented above that my comp sci professor recommended this during our first ever lecture, decades ago. He recommended a cat, but I suppose ea rubber duck would do. One thing is sure, it doesn't work without the anthropomorphic sidekick :-)

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the useful tools mentioned in other answers, I think modifying your mindset it useful when doing a code review.  It's silly, but I say to myself:  "I'm putting on my code review hat".  I do the same with QA.

Then it's important to *limit* yourself to that mindset.  You're either the reviewer or the reviewee, you can't be both at once.  So as a reviewer, I take objective notes to share with the reviewee.  I don't change the code while I'm reviewing it, that's not something a reviewer should do.

The formality feels a little absurd at times, but I find when working solo that I'm often pulled in a lot of directions.  So I may not necessarily close the review loop before something else comes up - that formality (and really, I'm talking rough notes in a wiki tool), is useful for making sure the review gets done.  Likewise with my QA hat on, I add tickets for bugs before I fix them.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to review your own code

Comment: @VJovic - I don't think I perform the best possible code review on my code, but I usually find things that could be improved.  I read a lot of other people's code too.  My viewpoint on what "good" code looks like is constantly evolving.  I'm embarrassed by code I wrote years ago.  It's no different than proofing your own article - it takes practice and a lot more effort, but it's doable.  The key thing I can't review myself is if an abstraction makes sense to someone else.  But I can ask myself how to make something simpler, is this necessary, etc.

Comment: @VJovic - As ThomasOwens mentioned, you can also create a checklist from past mistakes and run through that pretty objectively.  That's the other nice thing about being sort of formal about it, you can see what you missed during the review and adjust your process accordingly.  I find I learn a lot of lessons by tracking myself and making an effort to change my approach when indicated.

Comment: Getting into the right mindset is really important. I find that it helps if I actually print out the code and go through it on paper with a marker pen. Then I cannot change anything when reviewing (which prevents me from going into coding mode) and can easily scribble comments and movement arrows on the paper.

Comment: That means reviewing old code, and not new code. For that you need to gain experience, which can take long.

Answer (score 9):

It seems the common sentiment is that self-review is not effective. I disagree, and I think self-review can catch a lot of issues if done thoroughly.

Here are tips from my few years of experience:

- Have a rough checklist handy. These are things you want to flag while you read your code.
- Take your code review offline. It might sound wasteful, but take printouts that you can annotate and flip back-and-forth, or the digital equivalent of nicely highlighted pdfs synced to an iPad which is then taken offline. Go away from your desk, so that all you do is review your code distraction-free.
- Do it early in the morning, rather than the end of a working day. Fresh pair of eyes is better. In fact, it might help to have been away from the code a day before reviewing it afresh.

Just an FYI - these guidelines were part of recommendations in Oracle a few years ago when I was working there, where the aim was to catch bugs "upstream" before the code went into testing. It helped a lot, although it was considered boring job by a lot of developers.

Comment: I'd also add "wait 24 hours" so you aren't looking at code you just wrote. Make sure it's at least 1 day old so you are seeing it after sleeping overnight and not touching it for 24 full hours.

Comment: I often use printouts when I need to review or especially refactor some code. It works wonders for me.

Comment: Like in some film we learned from GB that a fake orgasm is better than no orgasm -- self-review is better than nothing. Yes, you can train to do rubberducking a lot. But it's still quite ineffective compared to actual peer review. especially without being exposed to actually good reviewers for some time to pick up methods.

Answer (score 8):

The Personal Software Process technique for reviews might be useful, although it relies on having historical data about your work and quality of products.

You start with historical data about your work products, specifically the number and types of defects. There are various methods of classifying defects, such as this [one from a PSP course](http://www.ipd.uka.de/mitarbeiter/muellerm/PSP/Dokumente/DefTyp/DefTyp.html). You can develop your own, but the idea is that you need to be able to tell what mistakes you are making along the way.

Once you know what mistakes you are making, you can develop a checklist that you can use during a review. This checklist would cover the top mistakes that you are making that you think can best be caught in a review (as opposed to using some other tool). Every time you review a work product, use the checklist and look for those mistakes or errors, document them, and fix them. Periodically revise this checklist from time to time to make sure you are focusing on real, relevant problems in your code.

I would also recommend using tool support when it makes sense. Static analysis tools can help find some defects, and some even support style checking to enforce consistency and good code style. Using an IDE with code completion and syntax highlighting can also help you prevent or detect some problems before you click "build". Unit tests can cover logic problems. And if your project is sufficiently large or complex, continuous integration can combine all of these into a regularly-run process and produce nice reports for you.

Answer (score 7):

Working solo means that unless you trust complete strangers to review code on your behalf, that you will need to look at the way you write your software in order to maintain code quality.

First and foremost, you should have a means to ensure that your code is matching requirements, and second that your code will be relatively easy to change if you decide later that you got something wrong. My suggestion would be to apply a [Behaviour Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behaviour_driven_development) approach for the following reasons:

1. BDD means writing code test first.  This ensures all of your code is covered by tests.
2. BDD is essentially TDD, but with a slightly different focus and "language". What this implies is that you continuously refactor your code as you are working on it, and use your tests to ensure your refactoring efforts continue to ensure that your code satisfies your product spec.
3. BDD language encourages tests to be written in the form of statements that essentially encode requirements as unit tests.

So the idea here, is that your continuous refactoring of code even after you get your tests to pass, means that you are effectively reviewing your own code and using your unit tests as the "extra pair of eyes" which make sure your code doesn't stray from the requirements that are encoded in the tests. Also, high test coverage based around requirements ensures you will be able to change your code in the future without failing the requirements.

The real issue for you will be whether or not you're able to spot potential issues in your code that will indicate a need to refactor.  There are several profiling tools on the market that can help you with this, as well as several other tools which are concerned with code quality metrics. These can often tell you many things that code reviews can miss, and are a must when developing projects on your own. In reality however, experience is the key, and once you are in the habit of being merciless in your refactoring, you will likely become much more critical of your own code.  If you haven't already, I'd suggest reading Martin Fowler's [Refactoring](http://www.bookdepository.com/Refactoring-Martin-Fowler/9780201485677) book as a starting point, and looking for a good BDD API that you feel will work for you in whichever language you have chosen to work with.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I've been in the same situation as yourself, I've tried to solve the problem of "being too close to the code to objectively examine it" by using code review / metric tools.  It goes without saying that a tool cannot give the same value as an experienced reviewer, but you can still use them to pinpoint areas of bad design.

One tool that I've found fairly useful in this regard was [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html).  It's a bit simplistic, but it gives a good mid-level opinion of your code, such as the number of methods in a class, and the complexity of each method.  I've always felt that this type of information was as important (if not more important than) the enforcement of coding styles via tools like StyleCop, etc (which are important, but are often not the source of the largest problems).  Use these tools with the usual disclaimers:  know when to break a rule of thumb, and something that is all green in a code metric tool isn't automatically of good quality.

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell you the number of times I have been explaining something to a code reviewer and the lightbulb in my head turns on and says, "Hey wait a minute." So I often find my own mistakes in the code review that the other person didn't see.  So you could try that, just start explaining the code as if there was a person sitting next to you who was trying to understand what you did and why.

Another thing that I find frequently in code reviews is that the developer did not actually follow the requirement. So comparing your code and what it does the the actual requirement is a good check.

We frequently do things like SSIS packages that have similar structural needs - for code reviews I developed a checklist of things to check (is the configuration correct, is logging set up, does it use the metadata database, are the files in the standard location, etc.). You might have some things that would be handy to check every time in a code review as well. Sit down and think about what you would put on a checklist of things you want to make sure to check in your code review (First item, make sure the requirement is met, next item might have something to do with trapping and logging errors). As you make mistakes and correct them, you may add other items to the list (say something like, do I move to the next record in a loop or am I going to endlessly repeat the same first item - it only take one endless loop to teach you to look for that!). This is mostly to keep you from forgetting to do some things that should be done.

Comment: As Patrick Hughes suggests in his answer, using a proxy like a rubber duckie to stand in for the reviewer helps the mindset.

Answer (score 5):

Give it 3 months, then go back and look at your code. I promise you, if you can't find something wrong with it (or question who wrote this junk!) you are a better man than I!

Comment: That's my technique also. 3 months is long enough that anything I can't immediately understand needs to be simplified or documented better, but short enough that I still remember what's going on enough to easily rectify it.

Answer (score 5):

I usually print out all my code and sit down in a quiet environment and read through it, I find a lot of typos, issues, things to refactor, cleanup by doing that. It's a good self-check that I think everyone should do.

Comment: A good addition to the advice above, thanks — although I think that a tablet or something like that (with editor, but without a development environment) would work too. I wonder who downvoted that and why.

Answer (score 4):

Back in college I was a writing tutor. It has certainly given me some perspectives on coding that I think many developers would never have thought of. One of the most important is to read your code aloud. It doesn't sound like much, but I will give a perfect example that I think everyone can relate to.

Have you ever written an email or a paper, reread multiple times to make sure its correct, then sent it, only to find that you have a glaring spelling error, typo or grammatical error? I just did this yesterday when I asked a client to press the shit key instead of the shift key. When you read in your head - you see what you want to see.

This is a shortcut for the 'just wait a day or a week or a month' suggestions others have made. If you read it aloud you catch the same things. I don't know why it is so effective, but after sitting with hundreds of students and having them read aloud, all I can say is that it works.

Comment: +1 This would go along with the "explain it to your cat" approach. Using different parts of your brain can be helpful when you can't use a co-worker.

Comment: plus one for shit key

Answer (score 3):

Most of the people tend to consider their code as their own babies and feed them with ego to rather than reality. Just like any other code reviews, review it as you're seeing someone else's code. Completely forget that you've wrote something. Review each line of the code. A check list would helpful for being aesthetics about reviewing own code. Automated tools for code review can help to some extend. I have used some tools like [klocwork](http://www.klocwork.com/) (commercial software), This is quite useful while you're working in large projects and several developers are working for it. Always focus on defect detection rather than correction.

But a best practice would be, review yourself and later involve at least two other people for review with distinguished roles.

Answer (score 3):

Consider doing a Fagan inspection by yourself - you'll have to adapt the process because you're by yourself, but you should be able to get quite a bit of value out of it.  The trick is going to be to find the right "ruleset" to evaluate your code against as a solo dev, and then having the discipline to ask those questions in a critical, analytical, merciless frame of mind each time.  I suspect you may want to brainstorm your own 4-5 crucial questions to start with, and then evolving it over time.  Some people are against formal inspections because they seem to be so time-intensive... before you decide that they're too expensive, bear in mind all the statistical evidence that doing inspections properly actually reduce project time.  Here's a Wikipedia link that you can start further research with:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_inspection

There have been a few books too, e.g. Google for "Software Inspection Process" by Strauss and Ebenau.

Another option is to pay someone to inspect an important project - or perhaps pay them occasionally to do inspections of all your code.  This guy's pretty good, we've flown him out a number of times to train our newer devs:

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the recommendations for code review, you can use the tools like PMD and findBug to do first level of sanity for your code.

Answer (score 0):

This has not actually been placed in an answer yet (but has been added as a comment to an existing answer)

Review your code after a good nights sleep, e.g. start the day by reviewing the code that you wrote the previous day.

This will of course not give you the collective experience of a team, but it will give let you review the code from a new perspective.

For instance, if you left a piece of code with a nasty hack, you might not be too inclined to fix it up, if you review your code immediately after. After all, when you start reviewing your code, you already know, and have accepted, the presence of this hack. But if you have had a good nights sleep you are probably more motivated to find a better solution.

When we sleep, the brain doesn't actually stop working on the problems that we have, so you might actually come up with a solution there, though those solutions [may sometimes present themselves in odd ways](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gImm40ImRyo).